# Find User Logged on to a Remote Computer

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have the following script. It should find the user who is currently logged into remote computer, but it doesn't. What am I missing? The remote computer is a part of a domain. Would I see to add the domain? How?

```
strComputer = "computername"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objComputer in colComputer
    Wscript.Echo "Logged-on user: " & objComputer.UserName
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `UserName` property returns the name of the user logged in on the console:

> **UserName**
>   [...]
>   Name of a user that is logged on currently. This property must have a value. In a terminal services session, **UserName** returns the name of the user that is logged on to the console—not the user logged on during the terminal service session.

If you don't get a result your user is most likely logged in via Remote Desktop.

To get all users logged in on the remote system [check the running Explorer processes for their owners](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2b99b836-ed8f-4146-89e4-947b79bf4862):

```
strComputer = "computername"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='explorer.exe'")
For Each p in objWMIService.ExecQuery(qry)
    p.GetOwner user, domain
    WScript.Echo "Logged-on user: " & domain & "\" & user
Next
```